# Gradient Sky In A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

How might I make a gradient color for the sky without using images?

This is what I have so far (I know why it doesn't work - it is only reference for what I am trying to do):

`<a-sky color="linear-gradient(red, yellow)"></a-sky>`

ThreeJS solutions welcome as well, but I would need help integrating them into an A-Frame scene.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js skydome with gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416458/three-js-skydome-with-gradient)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I am requesting help on how to integrate such a method into an A-Frame scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it with help from the given examples. Thank you Marko, Pablieros, ngokevin, and Mr Doob!

I ended up creating a custom shader and a primitive element to go along with it: 
`<a-gradient-sky material="topColor:0 1 0; bottomColor:1 0 0;"></a-gradient-sky>`

```
AFRAME.registerShader('gradient', {
  schema: {
    topColor: {type: 'vec3', default: '1 0 0', is: 'uniform'},
    bottomColor: {type: 'vec3', default: '0 0 1', is: 'uniform'},
    offset: {type: 'float', default: '400', is: 'uniform'},
    exponent: {type: 'float', default: '0.6', is: 'uniform'}
  },
  vertexShader: [
    'varying vec3 vWorldPosition;',

    'void main() {',

    'vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
    'vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;',

     'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );',

    '}'
  ].join('\n'),
  fragmentShader: [
    'uniform vec3 bottomColor;',
    'uniform vec3 topColor;',
    'uniform float offset;',
    'uniform float exponent;',
    'varying vec3 vWorldPosition;',
    'void main() {',
    ' float h = normalize( vWorldPosition + offset ).y;',
    ' gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( bottomColor, topColor, max( pow( max(h, 0.0 ), exponent ), 0.0 ) ), 1.0 );',
    '}'
  ].join('\n')
});

AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-gradient-sky', {
  defaultComponents: {
    geometry: {
      primitive: 'sphere',
      radius: 5000,
      segmentsWidth: 64,
      segmentsHeight: 20
    },
    material: {
      shader: 'gradient'
    },
    scale: '-1 1 1'
  },

  mappings: {
    topColor: 'material.topColor',
    bottomColor: 'material.bottomColor',
    offset: 'material.offset',
    exponent: 'material.exponent'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may want to** [Register a custom material/shader](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/material.html#register-a-custom-material) **similar to @ngokevin 's** [aframe-sun-sky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-sun-sky) **at** [ngokevin/kframe](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe) **or use** [registerShader](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/material.html#registershader)

Which would look something like following example from docs.

```
AFRAME.registerShader('hello-world-shader', {
  schema: {
    color: { type: 'vec3', default: '0.5 0.5 0.5', is: 'uniform' }
  },
  vertexShader: [
    'void main() {',
      '  gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;',
    '}'
 ].join('\n'),
 fragmentShader: [
   'uniform vec3 color;'
   'void main() {'
     '  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);',
   '}'
 ].join('\n')
});
```

And just for notice you tile says Skybox by aframe primitive `<a-sky>` is `geometry: { primitive: 'sphere' }`

Comment: Yeah I'm a total noob with 3d in the browser. A-Frame changed the game for me as I'm sure it has and will many 2d designers. Thank you for the lead though I will work on it and check it selected shortly.